# decodeByteArray crashing my application - android

Tags: android, bitmapimage, bitmapfactory, android-bitmap

In my emulator, Nexux5 4.1.2 Android (in 4.2.2 Android its working great) I get this errors:

```
01-31 19:32:05.528: E/AndroidRuntime(885): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-31 19:32:05.528: E/AndroidRuntime(885): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
01-31 19:32:05.528: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeByteArray(Native Method)
01-31 19:32:05.528: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:426)
01-31 19:32:05.528: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:444)
01-31 19:32:05.528: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at com.example.imhere.Home$14$1.done(Home.java:823)
01-31 19:32:05.528: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at com.parse.GetDataCallback.internalDone(GetDataCallback.java:20)
01-31 19:32:05.528: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at com.parse.GetDataCallback.internalDone(GetDataCallback.java:15)
01-31 19:32:05.528: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at com.parse.Parse$6$1.run(Parse.java:975)
01-31 19:32:05.528: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-31 19:32:05.528: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-31 19:32:05.528: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-31 19:32:05.528: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-31 19:32:05.528: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-31 19:32:05.528: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-31 19:32:05.528: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-31 19:32:05.528: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-31 19:32:05.528: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

*The line com.example.imhere.Home$14$1.done(Home.java:823) is:*
 **Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);**

***The 'data' is byte[].***

what I can do?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The error is `OutOfMemoryError`, which means what it says. You're trying to make an image out of a very large input. I'd investigate just how big the `byte[]` is and whether it makes sense that the resulting image would fit in memory on a phone.

Comment: But why is this happening only 4.1.2 version ? What I can do?
In the past I had this problem also other versions and I added the line :
android:largeHeap="true"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem each time I was trying to upload a photo and then display it in the same or in the next page. I found the below solutions that make my application has less `OutOfMemoryErrors`.

---

I added in `AndroidManifest.xml`, inside the `<application ... >` tag this line:
`android:largeHeap="true"`

---

Appart from the above, in each place I was decoded a byte array to convert it to bitmap, I did it exactly like this:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 5;

Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, options);
```